# access passing values between non related forms

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a main form, 1, a subform inside it, 2, and a popup form, 3.

**form 2** and **form 3** are datasheets. A button in **form 1** opens popup **form 3**.

Right now, in **form 2**, I capture the currently selected record and setup a query with the following [code](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0033.htm):

The query is a var named strSQL.

Is it possible to set strSQL as a property of **form 2** so I could set **form 3** record source as **Forms!1!2.forms!strSql** ? If not, what are my options of moving data from **form 2** to **form 3**, they're not related so I can't use OpenArgs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You CAN use OpenArgs for something like this.  You can pass a SQL string in OpenArgs if you wanted.  In fact, you can pass MULTIPLE SQL strings in OpenArgs, as long as you parse them out correctly.  I have an app where I pass 3 variables to another form using OpenArgs, and I pipe-delimit them (that is, I use the pipe key "|" to separate each variable, then parse them out when they get to the other form).  You can definitely use this methodology to accomplish what you're trying to do.

As an example, I'm using this code to pass a form, subform and field name to a new form:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , , , , stForm & "|" & stField & "|" & stSubForm
```

When I open that form, I'm parsing those values out using this code:

```
strForm = Left(Me.OpenArgs, InStr(Me.OpenArgs, "|") - 1)
Brk1 = Mid(Me.OpenArgs, InStr(Me.OpenArgs, "|") + 1)
strField = Left(Brk1, InStr(Brk1, "|") - 1)
strSubForm = Mid(Brk1, InStr(Brk1, "|") + 1)
```

Comment: Hmn, the problems is, strSql is in **form 2**, and **form 1** is the one opening popup 3. I'm trying to pass the string from **form 2** directly to **form 3**, I can't use openArgs there. Thanks for the piping tip tough, that's really usefull!

Comment: Try putting a hidden textbox on form 1 that gets updated when you capture the currently selected record in form 2.  Then you can easily pass the contents of that textbox to form 3.  I've definitely done that before.

Comment: It worked! On **form 2** i used `Me.Parent!txtPhoneNumber = strSQL`, the query then accesses **form 1** and retrieves the value, thank you!